# How to comment multiple lines in .story files (JBehave)

Tags: jbehave

Is there any way comment multiple lines in .story files?

If we want to comment single line, we will comment in following way
!-- abc

If we want comment 100 lines, how can we comment in single step instead of line by line comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse install "Eclipse Integration" plugin:
http://jbehave.org/eclipse-integration.html

And then you can comment and uncomment multiple lines in Story Editor using Ctrl-T shortcut.